# URL Error 2912 in fopen($url, "r")

Tags: php

I receive "error 2912" when I request a URL through `fopen($url, "r")` in PHP

Example:
It is actually on an sms API. I initiated some variables to substitute for some required fields.

```
$url = api.smartsmssolutions.com/smsapi.php?username=myusername&password=mypassword&sender=".$sender."&recipient=".$d3."&message=".$const_msg;
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the pgp error log that might be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

As per error 2912 your Recipient is empty. The correct format given is

```
http://api.smartsmssolutions.com/smsapi.php?username=YourUsername&password=YourPassword&sender=SenderID&recipient=234809xxxxxxx,2348030000000&message=YourMessage
```

Check by changing the url as below

```
    $username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
    $password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
    $sender   = "YOUR_ID";
    $d3       = "2348922223,2569878987";
    $const_msg = "YOUR_MESSAGE";
    $url = "http://api.smartsmssolutions.com/smsapi.php?username={$username}&password={$password}&sender={$sender}&recipient={$d3}&message={$const_msg}";
```

Comment: Pls why the big braces in the URL? I mean {... }

Comment: I have done that and it still gives the same error. My recipient is not empty bcs I had to echo it out on my page to see it.

Comment: can you do a var_dump($url); exit; This will dump the url value which will be easy to diagnose. Remember to put after $url variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error code 2912=Recipient is empty.
```

Please check correct value send by parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the variables were not initiated properly.
I had to use UrlEncode() in parsing the variables to the fopen($url).

Like This.

$urlt = "http://api.smartsmssolutions.com/smsapi.php?username=".UrlEncode($username)."&password=".UrlEncode($password)."&sender=" . UrlEncode($sender)
."&recipient=234" . UrlEncode($d3)
.",&message=" . UrlEncode($const_msg);